# SSL configuration in websphere 6.1

Tags: java, ssl, websphere, ibm-was

I am using WAS, websphere application server, 6.1 that comes as part of IBM RAD for development of an application. I want to configure `SSL` in the server so that I can use `https` rather than http to invoke my urls. I tried setting up the `keystore` and `certificates` in the security module of the WAS console, but could not complete the configuration. Please suggest steps to configure SSL in the server.

Comment: Websphere application server 6.1 should provide all the key and trust store to have SSL enabled by default. Are you not able to connect to your application installed on the server using https://<hostname>:<defaulthost_ secure>/<webappURI>? Please make sure that you are using correct secure port number (For example 9443) with https.

Comment: you'll need to elaborate on what you tried and what you observed.

Comment: WebSphere 6.1 is now very old and out of support so you should upgrade, but regarding that, it out of the box is supporting SSL. What might happen is that your browser is not allowing to establish SSL connection as probably that old WAS is still configured to SSL v3. Try to configure TLS in the application server SSL settings. And also try accessing using different browser.